# C# relational database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a relational table, where the connection is between users and notes. My problem

1. `_result.Entity.Id` returns -2147482647
2. I use Email as the key, but when creating more than one note there is an error stating that I already have such Email in the database, I would like to hear a solution to this problem.
3. My task is to match the Id notes in the two tables, but in the communication table id equals (see 1)

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(AddToDoViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ToDo toDo = new ToDo {Name = model.Tittle, Body = model.Body };
        var _result = await db.ToDos.AddAsync(toDo);

        UserToDo userToDo = new UserToDo { ToDoId = _result.Entity.Id, UserEmail = User.Identity.Name};
        var result = await db.UserToDos.AddAsync(userToDo);

        db.SaveChanges();

        return Redirect("/Profile");
    }

    return View(model);
}

public class ToDo
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

public class UserToDo
{
    [Key]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public int ToDoId { get; set; }
}
```

I will be very grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key is database-generated so you will have to give the db a chance to do just that:

```
var _result = await db.ToDos.AddAsync(toDo);
db.SaveChanges(); // this generates and fetches the new key
UserToDo userToDo = new UserToDo { ToDoId = _result.Entity.Id, UserEmail = User.Identity.Name};
```

And then you still have to SaveChanges a second time.  Look into Navigation properties for a better way.

With only the UserEmail as key in UserToDo, every user (email) can have only 1 ToDO item in your database.

```
public class UserToDo
{
    [Key]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    [Key] // add this to create a composite key
    public int ToDoId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to migrate UserToDo with two keys and I get this Entity type 'UserToDo' has a composite primary key defined with data annotations. To set a composite primary key, use fluent API

Comment: Better do as th error says: override OnModelCreating in your context class. Google for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

change this model to:

```
public class UserToDo
{
    [Key]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public int ToDoId { get; set; }
    public ToDo ToDo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why?  What do you expect from that?

Comment: @ Henk Holterman I had understand wrong thanks for your comment, I changed it.

Comment: This still has Email as a single Key. It might solve the `Id` issue, but not the 1 todo/email problem.